# How can i always show notes on tumblr footer?

Tags: html, footer, tumblr

How do i make the notes on your permalink/footer always show even if there's zero notes like "0 notes"?
These are what i've done:

```
{block:indexpage}
<div class="footer for_permalink">
<div class="date">
<a href="{Permalink}">
{timeago} </div><div class="notes">{block:NoteCount}{NoteCountWithLabel}   {/block:NoteCount}</a></div> {block:ifshowrebloglink}<div class="notes"><a href="{ReblogURL}" target="_blank" class="details">reblog</a> </div>{/block:ifshowrebloglink}
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>
{/block:indexpage}
```

but i can't get it to always show zero. 
so then i tried this:

```
{block:indexpage}
<div class="footer for_permalink">
<div class="date">
<a href="{Permalink}">
{timeago} </div><div class="notes">{block:PostNotes}{PostNotes} {/block:PostNotes}</a></div> {block:ifshowrebloglink}<div class="notes"><a href="{ReblogURL}" target="_blank" class="details">reblog</a> </div>{/block:ifshowrebloglink}
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>
{/block:indexpage}
```

but it still wont show zero notes. what am i doing wrong? I've googled it up, and most people say that you can't make it show zero notes when there are NO notes but this theme had no problem with it: http://unhacker.tumblr.com/bhthm

am i doing something wrong?

thanks in advance if u help and thank u for your time!!

Comment: Oh it's working!! Thanks so much mikedidthis!! :D

Answer (score 2):

**Displaying 0 Notes**

The theme operator`{block:NoteCount}` checks to see if the note count value is greater than zero and then renders the markup inside:

```
{block:NoteCount}
    {NoteCountWithLabel}
{/block:NoteCount}
```

However, we want to render the note count, whether it be zero or more. To do this remove the block and use the variable on its own:

```
{NoteCountWithLabel}
```